# Birt report deployment returns "Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'"

Tags: tomcat, jndi, birt

I am designing a report using Birt and Eclipse. When I deployed inside the Tomcat I am getting this problem.

```
 Jun 6, 2011 10:42:39 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager
                loadDriverExtensions
                INFO: Found JDBC driverinfo extension: driverClass=org.apache.derby.jdbc.Embedde
                dDriver, connectionFactory=null
                Jun 6, 2011 10:43:04 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager
                loadDriverExtensions
                INFO: Found JDBC driverinfo extension: driverClass=org.eclipse.birt.report.data.
                oda.sampledb.Driver, connectionFactory=org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.sampledb
                .SampleDBJDBCConnectionFactory
                Jun 6, 2011 10:43:04 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager$
                DriverClassLoader addNewURL
                INFO: JDBCDriverManager: found JAR file drivers/ojdbc14.jar. URL=bundleentry://4
                1.fwk12171472/drivers/ojdbc14.jar
                Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
                        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(B
                asicDataSource.java:1437)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDat
                aSource.java:1371)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSo
                urce.java:1044)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JndiDataSource.getDataSourceCon
                nection(JndiDataSource.java:178)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JndiDataSource.getConnection(Jn
                diDataSource.java:133)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getJndiDSConn
                ection(JDBCDriverManager.java:325)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDB
                CDriverManager.java:225)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection
                (JDBCDriverManager.java:212)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connect
                ion.java:237)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java
                :162)
                        at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.
                open(OdaConnection.java:250)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnec
                tion(ConnectionManager.java:165)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSo
                urce.java:224)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java
                :212)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource
                (DataSourceRuntime.java:208)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryE
                xecutor.java:406)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(Quer
                yExecutor.java:316)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQue
                ry.java:455)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQuer
                yResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(Pre
                paredDataSourceQuery.java:178)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(Prepared
                OdaDSQuery.java:145)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.exec
                ute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:616)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.ex
                ecuteQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:640)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.ge
                tResultSetForParameter(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1369)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.ge
                tChoicesFromParameterQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1341)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.do
                GetSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:515)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.ge
                tSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:445)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getParameterS
                electionList(BirtViewerReportService.java:821)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.parameter.ComboBoxPa
               ............................
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:16
                65)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
                Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
                        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
                        at .................
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.java:551)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
                patcher.java:488)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.SidebarFragment_jsp._jspS
                ervice(SidebarFragment_jsp.java:72)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
                icationFilterChain.java:290)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
                ilterChain.java:206)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
                atcher.java:646)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.java:551)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
                patcher.java:488)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.ReportFragment_jsp._jspSe
                rvice(ReportFragment_jsp.java:72)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
                icationFilterChain.java:290)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
                ilterChain.java:206)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
                atcher.java:646)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.java:551)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
                patcher.java:488)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.FramesetFragment_jsp._jsp
                Service(FramesetFragment_jsp.java:265)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at ...................
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:16
                65)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
                Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
                        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(B
                asicDataSource.java:1437)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDat
                aSource.java:1371)
                        at .............. org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.do
                GetSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:515)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.ge
                tSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:445)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getParameterS
                electionList(BirtViewerReportService.java:821)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.parameter.ComboBoxPa
                rameterFragment.prepareParameterBean(ComboBoxParameterFragment.java:91)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.parameter.ScalarPara
                meterFragment.doService(ScalarParameterFragment.java:91)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:76)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.dialog.ParameterDialogFragment_j
                sp._jspService(ParameterDialogFragment_jsp.java:109)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
                icationFilterChain.java:290)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
                ilterChain.java:206)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
                atcher.java:646)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.java:551)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
                patcher.java:488)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.dialog.DialogContainerFragment_j
                sp._jspService(DialogContainerFragment_jsp.java:135)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
                icationFilterChain.java:290)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
                ilterChain.java:206)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
                atcher.java:646)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.java:551)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
                patcher.java:488)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.SidebarFragment_jsp._jspS
                ervice(SidebarFragment_jsp.java:72)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
                icationFilterChain.java:290)
        ...........................
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:16
                65)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
                Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
                        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
                        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(B
                asicDataSource.java:1437)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDat
                aSource.java:1371)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSo
                urce.java:1044)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JndiDataSource.getDataSourceCon
                nection(JndiDataSource.java:178)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JndiDataSource.getConnection(Jn
                diDataSource.java:133)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getJndiDSConn
                ection(JDBCDriverManager.java:325)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDB
                CDriverManager.java:225)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection
                (JDBCDriverManager.java:212)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connect
                ion.java:237)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java
                :162)
                        at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.
                open(OdaConnection.java:250)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnec
                tion(ConnectionManager.java:165)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSo
                urce.java:224)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java
                :212)
                        ..........Some text
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.java:551)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
                patcher.java:488)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
                        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment
                .callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
                        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.dialog.DialogContainerFragment_j
                sp._jspService(DialogContainerFragment_jsp.java:135)
                        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
                .java:386)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
                13)
                        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
                icationFilterChain.java:290)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
                ilterChain.java:206)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
                atcher.java:646)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
                ispatcher.j
```

I configured web.xml and context.xml files and copied the ojdbc14.jar file into `webapps\birt\WEB-INF\platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.6.2.r262_v20110127\drivers` folder.

After running the report though browser I am getting this problem. Initially it is showing progress bar. But after some time (30min) it is showing blank report.

My query may take one hour to execute. But report showing blank with in 30min. What is the problem?

Comment: Could you post your context.xml and web.xml fragments, defining database connections (of course, "anonymize" them :) ) and your report xml fragment corresponding to connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it could be related to some kind of session timeout.  I believe that Tomcat has a default session-timeout set to 30 minutes.  I believe this setting is within the web.xml file.